# How can i change search result to google search result with Existing code in Genesis WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, genesis, wordpress-hook

I created a search Box by adding add_filter() code in my child theme `function.php` page .

The code is :

```
function add_search_to_wp_menu ( $items, $args ) {
    if( 'primary' === $args -> theme_location ) {
$items .= '<li class="menu-item menu-item-search">';
$items .= '<form method="get" class="menu-search-form" action="' . get_bloginfo('home') . '/"><p><input class="text_input" type="text" value="Click to Search" name="s" id="s" onfocus="if (this.value == \'Click to Search\') {this.value = \'\';}" onblur="if (this.value == \'\') {this.value = \'Click to Search\';}" /><input type="submit" class="my-wp-search" id="searchsubmit" value="search" /></p></form>';
$items .= '</li>';
    }
return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items','add_search_to_wp_menu',10,2);
```

This is working pretty well . Now i want to change my custom search to google search . I checked lot of tutorials on internet . But all the tutorials are saying about add `searchform.php` template on your child theme and do what ever you want .

My question is how can i add this google search code to the existing my search code in `function.php`. I Meant i have a google search code :

```
<script>

--google search code 

</script>
```

can i add this code directly to `function.php` instead of my existing search code in `function.php` instead of `$items .= '<form method="get" class="menu-search-form"`  ?